# Unable to reach service using DNS

Tags: node.js, dns, consul

I am using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package from NPM to handle some internal communication between services. I have also set the DNS server to the correct one (using Hashicorp Consul as my SD and DNS).

I can do a dig on my local machine (where the services are running) to the consul DNS server and I am able to get back the correct response (an IP and port number.

How I setup DNS in my app.js file6

```
dns.setServers([ `${config.consul.host}:8600` ]);
```

Set in a different file than app.js

```
options = {
    baseUrl: `http://auth.service.consul`,
    json: { '': '' },
    headers: { authorization: '' }
};
```

Same file as options above

```
request.post(req.path, options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(error);
    if (error) throw error;
    res.status(response.statusCode).json(body);
});
```

Error message:

```
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'auth.service.consul',
  host: 'auth.service.consul',
  port: 80 }
```

I am wanting to be able to make requests to the 'auth' service when using Consul as my DNS server. I currently have a very hacky way of doing this but really would like to use DNS.

I did find this but it is pertaining to the axios package not the request one I am trying to use even though it produces the same error the solution there didn't help.
[Consul service discovery with DNS on Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591751/consul-service-discovery-with-dns-on-nodejs)

Comment: If `dig` works against IP address set in `${config.consul.host}:8600` then dns.js might not be calling this DNS server for some reason. From documenation https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_setservers_servers  `The dns.setServers() method affects only dns.resolve(), dns.resolve*() and dns.reverse() (and specifically not dns.lookup()).`  I'm not very proficient in JavaScript, but try tracing down what DNS servers is your `request.post` trying to contact.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a chicken and egg problem.  Try resolving `${config.consul.host}` into an IP address and then call `dns.setServers` with that IP address.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, why would I set it to a variable when it is already one? That IP is a hard-coded value in my config file so it already has a value. Using template strings makes life easier since I don't have to concatenate everything into one variable. It just makes sense to use template strings instead of a new variable.

Comment: I assumed that `config.consul.host` was a hostname, not an IP Address.  My mistake.  You said that a `dig` returned you an IP and a port.  What type of record did you request with `dig`?  And what port was returned?